# Python Azure Function: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__'

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm triggering an Azure Function that fetches some data and writes it to a SQL db. The file Function works perfectly locally, but when I deploy it to Azure I keep getting the following error:

```
Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__'. Troubleshooting 
Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "/azure-functions- 
host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 301, in 
 _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions- 
host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 42, in call 
raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File "/azure-functions- 
host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call 
return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions- 
host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 83, in load_function 
mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return 
_bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File 
"/home/site/wwwroot/jobinfo/__init__.py", line 7, in <module> from .auth_and_get import * File 
"/home/site/wwwroot/jobinfo/auth_and_get.py", line 9, in <module> load_dotenv() File 
"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 317, in 
load_dotenv f = dotenv_path or stream or find_dotenv() File 
"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 265, in 
find_dotenv if usecwd or _is_interactive() or getattr(sys, 'frozen', False): File 
"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 262, in 
 _is_interactive main = __import__('__main__', None, None, fromlist=['__file__'])
```

In my Function file `__init__.py` I import a module `auth_and_get.py` where I've made methods, which I wanna call inside my Azure Function, and I think that something's wrong with my import, but I've tried fixing it without luck.

My current `__init__.py` file is

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from .auth_and_get import *


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    authenticate()
    users()
    to_db()

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

and I suspect that it's the following statment that fails: `from .auth_and_get import *`. I've tried removing the dot such that `from auth_and_get import *`, but then the module becomes unresolveable.

The structure is

```
ProjectFolder/
| - .venv
| - .vscode
|jobinfo/
| | - __pycache__
| | - __init__.py
| | - auth_and_get.py
| | - function.json
| | - sample.dat
| - .funcignore
| - host.json
| - local.settings.json
| - proxies.json
| - requirements.txt
```

**QUESTION**

- Why do I get the  `Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__'` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a variety of attempts, I found a solution by adding

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
```

to the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Remember you need to `import sys` and `import os` above that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set startup command on Azure Portal for your App Service?
I mean Settings->Configuration->General Settings and then in the field "Startup Command" you should have something like:

`gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 --chdir jobinfo __init__:<app object>`

Of course you can set another command (like non-Gunicorn), but it is an example based on Azure docs.

Azure by default looks for main module named `app.py` or `application.py`.

It's explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#customize-startup-command

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__'` means that Azure looks for module named `__main__` instead of `__init__`.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the `<app object>` is here?

Comment: So these settings are only available for a Python App, and not functions unfortunately.

Comment: The app object is a Flask instance in your main module/__init__.py. It looks like app = Flask(__name__) or something like app= Flask('yourapp') if it's defined in yourapp/app.py. There is more written about it in API documentation as 'Application  Object', but it wasn't, as we can see, a problem in your case :)